# Unable to show discount amount

Tags: magento

In Magento, I have created a module as per http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-discount-total-magento

But I am unable to show discount amount (see this http://d.pr/i/LSqW )

Seems in fetch function, `$address->addTotal()` is unable to show discounted amount. What could be the issue? Please help.

```
function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {
//code...
 ...
 ....
 $address->addTotal(array(
      'code' => 'Discount',
      'title' => 'Discount',
       'value' => $amt
        //'value' => '18' hardocded the amount, still not working
 ));

 //code...
 .....
 return $address;
}
```

Comment: please first estimate shipping then it should display

Comment: It is not dependent on shipping but I tried your way too but didn't work.

Comment: i think you forgot to return $address;

Comment: No return $address  is there. I have tried return $this too.

Comment: check this also hope this help you http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but I have already gone through it. ;-)

Comment: It was due to capital letter "D" is 'code' => 'Discount'.

I change it to 'code' => 'discount' and it works now :-)

Comment: grt :) @Satyam Saxena

Answer (score 0):

so the working code is

```
function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {
    //code...
     ...
     ....
     $address->addTotal(array(
          'code' => 'discount',
          'title' => 'discount',
           'value' => $amt
            //'value' => '18' hardocded the amount, still not working
     ));

     //code...
     .....
     return $address;
    }
```